# Error handling with dataframe.explode() in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

so I have some data that I am using the df.explode() method on. I get an error when running the code, I know the error is caused, because one of my rows (row 3) does not have a corresponding Qty for each location, but how can I handle that error ?

Code that returns ('ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis')

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

    data = {'ITEM': ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'],
        'Locations': ['loc1;loc2', 'loc3', 'loc4;loc5'],
        'Qty': ['100;200', '100', '500']
        }

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ITEM', 'Locations', 'Qty'])
    
    print(df1)
    
    formatted_df1 = (df1.set_index(['ITEM'])
                        .apply(lambda x: x.str.split(';')
                               .explode()).reset_index())
    
    print(formatted_df1)
```

Code that works (Note that the last record has 500;600):

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl


data = {'ITEM': ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'],
        'Locations': ['loc1;loc2', 'loc3', 'loc4;loc5'],
        'Qty': ['100;200', '100', '500']
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ITEM', 'Locations', 'Qty'])

print(df1)

formatted_df1 = (df1.set_index(['ITEM'])
                    .apply(lambda x: x.str.split(';')
                           .explode()).reset_index())

print(formatted_df1)
```

Comment: Any specific reason for ``set_index(['ITEM']``  & donot include images instead add actual code that allows other's to re-produce the issue ?

Comment: I have added the actual code, the one that does not work and the one that does work. I am setting ITEM to index so that I can have it appear for every row that Qty and location are split into.